A Newer movie about young business man
I'm trying to figure out an American film from a trailer i saw in theaters fairly recently. I believe it has been within 5 years from now. 
A young man gets hired into a business of some sort, his first big job and is then asked to be a double agent and steal secrets from another competing business. 
In the process women, cars and money are thrown at this young man from both sides and he starts to feel torn between the two businessmen. I'm thinking the young man is possibly dating the daughter of one the business men.
The main fact I recall the most is that one of the business men is a very popular actor. I was thinking it was Micheal Keaton or Kevin Costner but that's not the case.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from, what's "newer"? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Could be 'Paranoia' (2013)- Harrison Ford and Gary Oldman play dueling titans with Liam Hemsworth caught in the middle. He's dating one of their daughters. 

The two most powerful tech billionaires in the world (Harrison Ford and Gary Oldman) are bitter rivals with a complicated past who will stop at nothing to destroy each other. A young superstar (Liam Hemsworth), seduced by unlimited wealth and power falls between them, and becomes trapped in the middle of the twists and turns of their life-and-death game of corporate espionage. By the time he realizes his life is in danger, he is in far too deep and knows far too much for them to let him walk away.

